# Creating a delegating LdapAuthenticationProvider without using xml configuration, rather by java code

Tags: spring-boot, rest, spring-security, ldap, spring-ldap

I want to write a custom a LdapAuthenticationProvider as follows:

```
public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
        LdapAuthenticationProvider ldap = new LdapAuthenticationProvider(); // don't know how to do 
                                                                                  instantiate this 
        Authentication authentication1 = super.authenticate(authentication);
       return new LdapToken(null,null,"",true,"");
   }
```

My intention is to delegate the authentication to the default LdapAuthenticationProvider, but return some custom token after authentication.

But I am unable to create an object of LdapAuthenticationProvider since the build method of LdapAuthenticationProviderConfigurer which actually returns the object of LdapAuthenticationProvider is private. And I don't want to do it using XML configuration files.

Can anyone please let me know how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of directly invoking the `LdapAuthenticationProvider`, you need to use the [`AuthenticationManager`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.12.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/authentication/AuthenticationManager.html).

You need to expose it as an injectable bean in your configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }
}
```

Assuming your LdapAuthenticationProvider is a detectable Bean, the `AuthenticationManager` will be automatically injected with it.

Comment: Then how it will know that it has to call the LdapAuthenticationProvider authentic method? This is a class provided by spring security itself. I want to keep the default ldap provider, but at end I want to return my own type token. I have my own filter and token class as well. But facing issues with the provider